# If I add cv2.VideoCapture() to the list, ret is false

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, camera

I'm connecting to my desktop and using 5 cameras.
It works fine when using the following code.

```py
import cv2
camPorts = [6, 4, 8, 0, 2]


# im =[]
for cam in range(0, len(camPorts)):  # self.camNum
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(camPorts[cam])
    print(camPorts[cam])
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'))
    if cap.isOpened():
        # im.append(cap)
        ret, image = cap.read()
        print("Line")
        print(ret)
        print(image)
```

However, i remove commnet(#) causes problems in code.

```py
import cv2
camPorts = [6, 4, 8, 0, 2]


im =[]
for cam in range(0, len(camPorts)):  # self.camNum
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(camPorts[cam])
    print(camPorts[cam])
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'))
    if cap.isOpened():
        im.append(cap)
        ret, image = cap.read()
        print("Line")
        print(ret)
        print(image)
```

When cam is either 6 or 8, ret become false and image is None. (Sometimes both apply. but Almost always only one applies)
Even if the order of 'camports' changes, only '6' or '8' will be applied.

I don't understand this reason.
i always be grateful for the help.

addition information:
i changed list to set, not changed

Comment: The answer is NO!. That code only run on one camera.